# Auto generating storybook stories for expo and react-native-elements v4

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, storybook, react-native-elements

I've recently been involved in two different projects, each with its own unique documentation setup. In one project, I was working on a Next.js application where we used Storybook as our documentation system and Material-UI (MUI) for the UI components. The great thing about this setup was that the MUI components were automatically documented, which made our lives a lot easier.

Now, I'm working on another project, which is built with Expo and utilizes React Native Elements v4 as the UI kit. One challenge we've encountered is the manual documentation process for these components. However, I believe TypeScript can play a significant role in automating the documentation generation process.

Is there a way to streamline the documentation process for React Native Elements v4 using TypeScript, similar to what we experienced with MUI in the Next.js project?